# Check if property has changed

Tags: c#, properties, save, reset

I'm having a window with a menu bar. There are 3 menu items (Commands):

- New File
- Load File
- Save File

In my MVVM, I have several propertys. If the user loads a file, the propertys will be filled.
The user can do something in the program (change the value of the propertys..) and can Save the values of the propertys to a xml file.
So if the user saves the file and clicks 'New File', a new file will be created, which means I will 'reset' all propertys.
If the user does something in the program and didn't save the file and clicks then on 'New File', a MessageBox should pop up.
It should say 'Do you really want to save the file,.... unsaved files will be overwritten' (guess you know what I mean..)

So to clear it up, here are some scenarios:

- User changes propertys in program and clicks on 'New File' -> MessageBox pops up
- User changes propertys in program and clicks on 'Save File' and clicks on 'New File' -> Propertys will be reseted
- User clicks on 'Load File' and clicks on 'New File' -> Propertys will be reseted

So how am I supposed to check if a property has changed? I could have a global boolean 'HasChanged'. 
If the user clicks on Save or Load, `HasChanged = false`. If the user does something, `HasChanged = true`... 
I could put this in every setter of a property, but that's a stupid solution...

Comment: You can set the flag after hooking up to [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event inside the view model...

Comment: I'm using PropertyChanged like this `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Number);` and use it from ObservableObject, so I can't change the method.

Comment: But you can subscribe to the *event* inside the view model. It will be fired every time any property that notifies is changed...

Comment: Thanks... easy solution, didn't think of that at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example. Add a virtual (or implement directly in the base class) and create an IsDirty flag. I always create a base class and implement those methods there and create some OnSaved(), OnLoaded() etc. protected virtual methods. In this case you can have a base functionality but still able to add custom logic in the inherited classes.

```
  public bool IsDirty { get; private set; }

  protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
     var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

     if (handler != null)
     {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
     }
  }

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
     IsDirty = true;
  }

  public void Save()
  {
     IsDirty = false;
  }
```